# Cannot connect to web server when using route prefix in the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications

I'm able to connect to the server when I use `http://127.0.0.1:8003` url for both client and server. But, when I try to add additional route to it such as `http://127.0.0.1:8003/service`, I get this error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:8003)

So, how can I add route prefixes?

Client:

```
var restClient = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8003");
var request = new RestRequest("do_stuff");
request.AddJsonBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyInfo {}));
var res = await restClient.PostAsync(request);
```

Server:

```
var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
var app = builder.Build();
    
app.MapPost("do_stuff", ([FromBody] MyInfo args) =>
{
    return Results.Ok();
});
    
appTask = app.RunAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8003");
```

**UPDATE - Using UsePathBase**

**Client**

```
var restClient = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8003/service");
var request = new RestRequest("do_stuff");
```

**Server**

```
    var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UsePathBase("/service");
    app.UseRouting();
        
    app.MapPost("do_stuff", ([FromBody] MyInfo args) =>
    {
        return Results.Ok();
    });
        
    appTask = app.RunAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8003/service");
```

Comment: Do you wanna add a Global Route Prefix like `http://127.0.0.1:8003/service/xxxx` in your server?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna your application accept a route prefixes, you can try to add

```
app.UsePathBase("/service");
```

in your middleware pipeline, this middleware can split the specified prefix from Path to PathBase if the request has the prefix.

now when you send url like `http://127.0.0.1:8003/service/xxx`, it will route to the correct endpoint.

More details refer to [link](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-pathbase-in-aspnetcore/).

Comment: I just had time to try it. I updated my post what I tried, but `do_stuff` never gets called and I still get the same error. What am I missing?